# Statistic T-Test & T-table

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance

Hi can anyone help me with this question . Thank you!

[image]

I know that for part (a) degree of freedom is 13.
But how do I use the t-table to answer (b) and (c). The t-table is below

[image]

Comment: Note that "quartiles" in the table header is a typo for "quantiles".

Comment: I highlighted the column with degree of freedom 13. But which number should I use. It is a one sided T-test so there should be one critical value so what part (b) asked for two values?

Comment: This table provides critical values of a Student $t$ statistic for some degrees of freedom *and* some value $q$ of interest. It is unlikely that your observed test statistic (2.55) will be in this table, and you need to find what are the closer values from this table. This will help answering (c) and (d).